# How to acknowledge push webservices

Tags: java, web-services, architecture

I have a web-service on my server that pushes the xml data to the clients that are communicating to it over internet.

1. In these cases we have challenge to receive  acknowledgement from the
   client.
2. Specific case like, once client has received the data and before
   sending the acknowledge, if the communication channel goes down.

   Example:
   In case of the software updates on clients over internet, how the server makes sure every thing is processed fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go on the "push" path, and you absolutely must know if the update was succesful, then you have to build your service and clients in such a way that you do know.

Basically what you need to do is build a small protocol so that information is transmitted no matter the failures of the communication channel. This means two things:

- Your service does re-transmissions;
- Your clients can deal with duplicate messages;

For example:

1. service pushes a message, client acknowledges => all good;
2. service pushes a message, the connection goes down, the message is lost. The client does not acknowledge since it never got the message => service pushes that same message once again at some later time. Now hopefully you get to case 1.
3. service pushes a message, client acknowledges but the connection fails and the service does not receive the acknowledge => similar to 2, so the service pushes that same message once again some later time and now the client receives the same message twice. It must ignore the second message but still needs to send an acknowledge so the service does not send it a third, forth, ... nth time;

And so on and so forth...

This is a high level description of what [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) does, for example. TCP is a reliable protocol over an unreliable network. It handles dropped packets, duplicated packets, etc.

Now, that would be pushing. A more simple alternative would be to use "pull" instead. The clients periodically pull the updates from the server. This is simpler to implement (the download is succesful if it worked, otherwise you try again later) but it's not without its gotchas, like for example:

- controlling when clients start to pull data from the service. You can't just have them all update  at  the same time or you might overload the server. Clients should first ask the server if it's OK to update now or comme back later when the service is  not so busy;
- are you downloading upgrades in the background, from user devices? Data charges might apply so maybe it's better to ask the user if it wants the update now or later instead of doing it behind the scenes;
- updating in the background, even if there is no problem with data charges might still consume bandwith when the client needs that bandwith for something else;

And so on and so forth...

The thing is this is a large topic, with general solutions that might not apply given particular situations. But it is not a new topic. Others have had these issues before. Consider for example Windows updates, how each PC's OS updates itself. Something similar happened a while ago when thick clients needed updates. The world moved to thin clients but now thick clients are making a comeback. Have a look at how these issues are solved, you will find usefull information online.

Comment: Is this same approach that software updates on end devices are done? It sounds like the we need to avoid writing push services. If that is the case what are alternatives we can look for?

Comment: @BValluri: I have updated my answer. See if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a way to do that. I believe the reason you are asking is for the following reasons:

**1) If you are asking because you are sending a lot of data and your client deny receiving it, perhaps you can paginate it.** That way you will know when the last page was accessed. You can even go one step further and just put very little data on your last page, that way you are sure that the last page is called.

**2) If you are genuinely concerned about ensuring that they receive the entire data.** How about suggest they access a 2nd web service which contains the checksum for the data, and suggest that they compare it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your web service is [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), your server should be stateless. The *client* should make sure it receives the data properly.

You could define a service to get the [hash value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) of the data, followed by the request to receive the data itself. The client can check after the download whether the hash value of the downloaded data corresponds to the value received by the first call.

Amongst others, you could use `MD5`, `SHA-1` and `SHA256` in standard Java, as described in the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html). This will calculate the hash value of the data from the server side.

Assuming you use Javascript from the client side, there are many possibilities to calculate the hash code using the same algorithms ([jsSHA](https://caligatio.github.io/jsSHA/), for example).

I hope it helps.